# libgdx interstitial ads with admob

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I'm having trouble showing interstitial ads when the player in my game dies.

I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) for implementing ads with admob but I got stuck at the "show the ad" part. How do I show it in my game when the player dies? Do I have to call some method? I've seen another question like this but I think the answer is outdated. Does someone have experience with this? This is all the code I have.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    protected AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adView = new AdView(this);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new ShootGame(), config);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you have to call if(interstitialAd!=null && interstitialAd.isLoaded()){ interstitialAd.show()}

Comment: But how do I get access to the interstitial ad object form my game classes?

Comment: move adcode except MobileAds.initi...  to your game class

Comment: I only have access to `com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd` from the `AndroidLauncher` for some reason

Comment: And in the tutorial it says this: Interstitial ads are requested and shown by InterstitialAd objects. The first step is instantiating InterstitialAd and setting its ad unit ID. **This is done in the onCreate() method** of an Activity:

Comment: post your game activity class's oncreate methd

Comment: It's the one in my question, isn't it the only one?

Comment: you want to load ad from this class?

Comment: I don't know, I want to show an ad when the player dies and after the ad the menu screen should be run. I don't have any experience with admob, I was just following the tutorial.

Comment: I think so, thank you, but the ad doesn't show. I did everything as shown in your answer

Comment: IT WORKS! I guess it took some time for the ad to register. Thank you very much!!!